# How do you specify the range a formula statement applies to?

Tags: excel

The set-up:

- A master data tab
- Several tabs that parse the data in the master data tab

In order to extract the information from the Master data tab I am using the below:

`=FILTER(MasterTable[ColumnName],MasterTable[ColumnName2]="Foo")`

This gives me an array of all the rows in my new sheet. However, I now wish to perform an IF statement against this in the next column. I am trying to make this automated as the master data tab will be updated regularly.

I can of course get the length of the filtered array with:

`=ROWS(FILTER(MasterTable[ColumnName],MasterTable[ColumnName2]="Foo")`

But I am unsure how to use this to specify how many cells should contain the IF statement in the next column.

Any suggestions? (Not VBA - I am trying to make this simple for other users)

Sudo Code

`=FOR ROWS(6): IF col1 > col2 then "Yes"`

To create 6 stacked cells that all perform the same way.

Comment: The IF will need to be applied to all rows, this is automatic in a table.

Comment: @SJR - The IF statement cannot exist within a table as the FILTER() function will not work within one as it causes a #SPILL! error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found I can use the reference to the dynamic/spill function FILTER() through the use of "#" e.g. "B2#" so:

`=IF(INDEX(MasterTable[Column1],MATCH(B2#,MasterTable[Column2],0))<>"", "True")`

This will generate a spill IF function. I have some testing to do but I believe this is the way to go.